# Keyboard configuration switcher

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xrdp

**EDIT**:
I don't know what changed from two days ago, but now I see the same problem in the 20.04 box.

In Ubuntu 22.04 I have configured *Tweaks* -> *Keyboard & Mouse* -> *Additional Layout Options* -> *Switching to another layout* -> *Left Alt + Left Shift*.

I am connecting via xRDP from a Win 10 box (see [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420840/heavily-edited-question-spanish-latin-american-keyboard-randomly-changing)), and *Left Alt + Left Shift* does not switch keyboards in the remote (as it does in the client Win 10).
I used to be able to switch keyboards in another similarly remotely-accessed Ubuntu 20.04 box.

**Is there anything else I need to configure?**

Comment: This may be an additional aspect of [bug #1956916](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1956916).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson - Maybe. I am not on Wayland, and I do have the option, in Tweaks.

Comment: Ok, then it's probably not that bug. Especially considering you also see it on 20.04.